# Exception while using EnumType support of Hibernate4

Tags: hibernate

Please let me know the fix for this exception. While using the above fetch API i am getting the exception mentioned above. The database i have used is mysql. I have mapped java Enumeration to varchar of mysql and it is inserting the rows properly. But while obtaining value from db it gives above exception. I think it is not able to map mysql varchar to java enumeration.

EXCEPTION:

```
ERROR: Unknown column 'FOLDER' in 'where clause'
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Unknown column 'FOLDER' in 'where clause'
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at $Proxy5.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2031)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1832)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1811)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:899)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2516)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2502)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2332)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2327)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1247)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
    at doa.ActionDetailsDOA.fetchActionDetailsByCircleIdProfileIdElementTypeAndactionId(ActionDetailsDOA.java:24)
    at doa.ActionDetailsDOA.main(ActionDetailsDOA.java:41)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'FOLDER' in 'where clause'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2542)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1734)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1885)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
    ... 18 more
```

The DataModel sample is :

```
public class ActionDetails implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private AId id; // containing composite primary key
    private int parentId;
}

public class AId implements Serializable{
        private int fldCircleId;
    private int fldProfileId;
    private ElementType elementType;
}

class Folder extends ActionDetails {
    // contains attributes provided in ActionDetails.hbm.xml
}

class Item extends ActionDetails {
   // contains attributes provided in ActionDetails.hbm.xml
}
```

The sample of ActionDetails.hbm.xml:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="model.ActionDetails" table="action_details">
        <composite-id name="id" class="model.ActionDetailsId">
            <key-property name="fldCircleId" type="int">
                <column name="fld_circle_id" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="fldProfileId" type="int">
                <column name="fld_profile_id" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="elementType">
                <column name="element_type" length="7" />
                <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
                    <param name="enumClass">model.ElementType</param>
                    <param name="type">12</param> <!-- 12 corresponds to java.sql.Types.VARCHAR -->
                </type>
            </key-property>
        </composite-id>

        <discriminator column="element_type"  insert="false"/>


        <property name="parentId" type="int">
            <column name="parent_id" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="elementIndex" type="int">
            <column name="element_index" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="level" type="int">
            <column name="level" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="oldActionId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="old_action_id" />
        </property>
        <property name="elementDetails" type="string">
            <column name="element_details" length="1000" />
        </property>

        <set name="menuHighestActionIds" table="menu_highest_action_id" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="fld_circle_id" not-null="true" />
                <column name="fld_profile_id" not-null="true" />
                <column name="element_type" length="7" not-null="true" />
                <column name="highest_action_id" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="model.MenuHighestActionId" />
        </set>
        <!-- Attributes of Folder.java -->

        <subclass name="model.Folder" discriminator-value="FOLDER">
            <property name="folderId" type="java.lang.Integer">
                <column name="folder_id" />
            </property>
            <property name="title" type="string">
                <column name="title" length="20" />
            </property>
        </subclass>

        <!-- Attributes of Item.java -->
        <subclass name="model.Item" discriminator-value="ITEM"> 
            <property name="softId" type="java.lang.Integer">
                <column name="softid" />
            </property>
            <property name="title" type="string">
                <column name="title" length="20" />
            </property>
            <property name="description" type="string">
                <column name="description" length="50" />
            </property>
            <property name="subscriptionInfo">
                <column name="subscriptioninfo" length="35" />
                <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
                    <param name="enumClass">model.SubscriptionInfo</param>
                    <param name="type">12</param><!-- 12 corresponds to java.sql.Types.VARCHAR -->
                </type>
            </property>
            <property name="commandType">
                <column name="commandtype" length="13" />
                <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
                    <param name="enumClass">model.CommandType</param>
                    <param name="type">12</param> <!-- 12 corresponds to java.sql.Types.VARCHAR -->
                </type>
            </property>
            <property name="keyword" type="string">
                <column name="keyword" length="10" />
            </property>
            <property name="shortcode" type="java.lang.Integer">
                <column name="shortcode" />
            </property>
        </subclass>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The sample od ActionDetailsDOA.java :

```
public List<ActionDetails> fetchActionDetailsByCircleIdProfileIdElementTypeAndactionId(int circleId, int profileId, ElementType elementType, int actionId) throws Exception{
    try{
        hibSession = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        tx = hibSession.beginTransaction();
        Query query = hibSession.createQuery("from ActionDetails as ad where ad.id.fldCircleId="+circleId+" and ad.id.fldProfileId="+profileId+" and ad.id.elementType="+elementType+" and ad.id.actionId="+actionId);
        List list = query.list();
        System.out.println(list);
        tx.commit();
        return null;
    }catch(Exception exception){
        tx.rollback();
        throw exception;
    }finally{
        if(hibSession != null){
            hibSession.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue, it was due to the HQL behaviour while dealing with EnumType in where clause.

I updated my HQL query to

Query query = hibSession.createQuery("from ActionDetails as ad where ad.id.fldCircleId="+circleId+" and ad.id.fldProfileId="+profileId+" and ad.id.elementType='"+elementType+"' and ad.id.actionId="+actionId);

from: 
Query query = hibSession.createQuery("from ActionDetails as ad where ad.id.fldCircleId="+circleId+" and ad.id.fldProfileId="+profileId+" and ad.id.elementType="+elementType+" and ad.id.actionId="+actionId);

and the things were done for me.

Ajay